# Is there a way to understand if a SASS variable is a valid color?

Tags: css, if-statement, sass, colors

I would like to know if a variable is a valid color in a SASS function.
This is the first code I wrote, so I check if the variable is initialised.

```
@function get-valid-color($color) {
  @if variable-exists($color) {
    @return $color;
  } @else {
    @return inherit;
  }
}
```

I would like to understand also if the variable is a valid color or not. Only in that case I would return the variable, otherwise I would return `inherit`.

This the expected output:

```
  $primary-text = red;
  $primary-bg = #000000;
  $border-width = 4px;

  color: get-color($border-width);           // color: inherit;
  background-color: get-color($primary-bg);  // background-color: #000000;
  color: get-color($primary-text);           // color: red;
  color: get-color($fake-variable);          // color: inherit
```

Ideas, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a built-in method in SASS ([`type-of()`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/meta#type-of)) that might help to check if the current existing color is actually is a color or not, so you can check it like this:

```
@function get-valid-color($color) {
  @if type-of($color) != color {
    @return inherit;
  } @else {
    @return $color;
  }
}
```